# Add Image to Brand - Rails - Twitter_Bootstrap_Rails Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I am using the twitter-bootstrap gem (https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails) in my rails app.  I am trying to create a simple nav bar with some search functionality.  I would like to be able to replace the 'Brand' text with an image, but can't seem to figure it out.

Here is an example from the GitHub page.  How would I add an image to the code below?

```
<%= nav_bar :fixed => :top, :brand => "Fashionable Clicheizr 2.0", :responsive => true do %> 
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would like to do something like this:

```
<%= nav_bar :fixed => :top , :brand => image_tag('MySitelogo.png') , :responsive => true do %>
<% end %>
```

or else do something like this if you already have nav_bar divs defined with usual html

```
<%= image_tag 'MySitelogo.png', :class => "brand" %>
```

hope it helps! :)